# how to use the same mutableLiveData in ViewModel from fragment and dialog fragment

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel, android-dialogfragment, mutablelivedata

I have a ViewModel, that I used in Fragment and DialogFragment. In Dialog Fragment, I try to update MutableLiveData value in Dialog Fragment and then use that value from MutableLiveData in my Fragment. as I check In Dialog Fragment I have data inside MutableLiveData but when trying to access that data inside fragment I got null. may please guide me on how to fix this problem?

in ViewModel:

```
val width = MutableLiveData<String>()
val height = MutableLiveData<String>()
val length = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

in DialogFragment:

```
vModel.width.value = "6"
vModel.height.value = "6"
vModel.length.value = "6"
```

and in my fragment that when I try to access data from MutableLiveData:

```
println(vModel.width.value)
println(vModel.height.value)
println(vModel.length.value)
```

this is my BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<B : ViewDataBinding, V : BaseViewModel>(
    private val layout: Int,
    private val viewModel: V
) : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var v: View
    protected lateinit var binding: B
    protected lateinit var vModel: V


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layout, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        this.vModel = viewModel


        initVariables()
        initObserves()
        initViews()

        return binding.root
    }

    abstract fun initVariables()
    abstract fun initObserves()
    abstract fun initViews()

}
```

this is my BaseDialogFragment:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment<B : ViewDataBinding, V : BaseViewModel>(
    private val layout: Int,
    private val viewModel: V
) : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var v: View
    protected lateinit var binding: B
    protected lateinit var vModel: V


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layout, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        this.vModel = viewModel


        initVariables()
        initObserves()
        initViews()

        return binding.root
    }

    abstract fun initVariables()
    abstract fun initObserves()
    abstract fun initViews()

}
```

Comment: You should post whole story. Looks like your view model is not exactly shared view model.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you load your ViewModel with activity context so one instance will be shared with all fragments, and not be recreated for each one

something like this

```
val viewModel by activityViewModels<MainViewModel> ()
```

Comment: I use this BaseFragment and BaseDialogFragment. is it wrong?

Comment: you can check this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel 
take a look at "Share data between fragments",